# How to redirect only for products of a given date

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, product

I have some products published on 24 october 2014
how can I check the date of product and then change add to cart link for this product?

I have this code in foonctions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
return 'http://mylink.com/28653'; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use filter [`woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id`](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/filters/woocommerce_add_cart_item/)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'rv_redirect_on_add_to_cart' );
function rv_redirect_on_add_to_cart() {

//Get product ID
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {

    $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );

//get date by ID...
//compare date
//return link
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you made a copy/paste error as you link to `woocommerce_add_cart_item` and then filter `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` in your code. I think your code is correct, though I'd switch to `$_REQUEST` from `$_POST` since that's what WooCommerce uses.

Comment: I'd still switch to `$_REQUEST` so that it works with URL add to carts, ex:  `/?add-to-cart=99`

Comment: Could you add a date checking condition? @andrey-shandrov this should help.